# Is it true that here will be strict inequality in interlacing of eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B,C$ be full rank ,real symmetric matrices. Consider $H=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} A&\begin{array}{ccc} 0&\cdots&0\\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\0&\cdots&1 \end{array}&O\\\begin{array}{ccc} 0&\cdots&0\\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\0&\cdots&1\end{array}&B&\begin{array}{ccc} 0&\cdots&0\\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\0&\cdots&1
\end{array}\\O&\begin{array}{ccc} 0&\cdots&0\\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\0&\cdots&1
\end{array}&C
\end{array} \right)$ (all dots stand for zeros.)

where $O$ is the zero matrix of respective order.

let $P$ be submatrix of $H$ obtained by removing rows and columns corresponding to last row of $A$ and $B$.
By "Interlacing Theorem", we know that eigenvalues of $P$ will be interlaced among eigenvalues of $H$.

Is it true that here will be strict inequality in interlacing? In general, what will be the condition on $A,B$ to guarntee strict inequality in interlacing?

I tried some examples in matlab and found inequalities to be strict in $H$ and $P$. But have no idea how to proceed. Any help or reference is highly welcome.

Comment: I don't know what $0\quad\cdots\quad1$ means. Are the dots all zeros? all ones? something else?

Comment: yes, all dots stand for zeros.